# accessing string on ar_list does error on windows

Tags: c, arrays, string, variadic-functions

why does this function crashes on Windows and does good on Linux?

I found the problem is the line `printf("%d ..... %s", i < count ? i : 0 , string);`, because if I try "test" instead of the parameter string, the menu does well. I suspect that I'm trying to access an element outside the string indices, but it just happens on windows, there's no segmentation fault signal under Linux.

```
void menu(int count, ...) {

va_list listPointer;

va_start(listPointer, count);

for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    char *string = va_arg(listPointer, char*);

    printf("\n%d ..... %s", i < count ? i : 0 , string);
}

va_end(listPointer);
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Thanks for your time.

EDIT: the compiler I use for running on linux is gcc. But I need to run this under Windows (mingw).
The call I make to the menu is `menu(3, "option1", "option", "option3");` and is just once in the code.

Comment: Can you show us how you call `menu`?

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: gcc on linux, my computer; but I'm installing this library on a school that asked to. They use mingw compiler.

Comment: @DyP , sure, on the program you can use: menu(3, "option 1", "option 2", "option 3");  and the menu will create itself from this function right away. It's a nice function, in my opinion; instead of multiple printfs. But I have to have this resolved until Monday. I never used windows to program so I don't get why mingW isn't allowing that call. Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is nothing in that code that could cause a segfault, assuming that menu() is called properly. Can you show how you call menu()? You must be calling it improperly somewhere else in the code.

Comment: "you can use" So the call that leads to a segfault really uses string literals (and not variables)? I suggest 1) Try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). This help you proof that the problem really stems from this portion of the code, and helps us reproduce the problem. 2) Tell us the versions of the compilers you use. Maybe (but IMO improbably) this is related to a compiler bug.